# ActiveRecord query to join Posts, post authors and likes in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, join, activerecord

So, I have read through quite a few rails active records pages, stack O questions and answers (about 12 hours of time) trying to figure out how the heck to tie all of these things together into a single query to display them on my page.

Here is my page view

```html
Secrets with owner info
   </h3>
   <% @secretInfo.each do |i| %>
    <p><%= i.content %> - <%= i.first_name %></p>
    <p><%= i.created_at %></p>
    --> "this is where I'd like to have likes for post" <--
   <% end %>
```

and here is my controller

```html
def show
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @secrets = Gossip.all
    @mySecrets = Gossip.where(user_id: [params[:id]])
    @secretInfo = Gossip.joins(:user).select("content", "first_name", "created_at")
    @secretWLikesNInfo = WTF MATE?
  end
```

Also, may help to see my models and schema so here are those

```html
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password
  has_many :gossips
  has_many :likes
  has_many :liked_secrets, :through => :gossips, :source => :gossip


class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :gossip
                               
class Gossip < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :likes
  has_many :liking_users, :through => :likes, :source => :user
```

I don't know why this seems so impossible or it could be something very simple that I am just overlooking. This all was very easy in PHP/MySQL. All help is appreciated.

Additional points for coming up with a query that allows me to see all posts that I as a user has created AND liked!

Answer (score 0):

Well, what you want to do is eager loading: load data associated with a record in a single roundtrip to the database. For example, i think you can load all your data like this:

```
@user = User.where(id: params[:id])
            .joins(:liked_secrets)
            .includes(:liked_secrets => :likes)
            .first!

@secretInfo = @user.liked_secrets.map do |secret|
  OpenStruct.new(
    content: secret.content,
    first_name: user.first_name,
    created_at: secret.created_at,
    likes: secret.likes
  )
end
```

This works by including in the data fetched from the database in the first query all the data associated included in the `include` parameter. So, calling `@user.liked_secrets` will return the secrets but won't call the database because that information already came from the database in the first query. The same happens if you do `@user.liked_secrets.first.likes` because of the `:linked_secrets => :likes` parameter on the initial query.

I'll let a link to a good blog post about this here: 
http://blog.arkency.com/2013/12/rails4-preloading/.

And, if you feel the Rails ORM (ActiveRecord) doesn't really works for your use case, you can just use sql in a string or fallback to use another Ruby ORM out there (like Sequel).